# How to change block order in layout xml

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, xml

I'm using the luma demo for practicing. 
I want to create and add a new block in my homepage like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <block name="myblock"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

It worked but I want to change this block's order before the tag "main" which class name is "page-main".

I've tried this code :

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper" before="main"> or
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper" before="page.main"> or
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper" before="page-main">
```

None of this works.
Even I put a move tag like this:

```
<move element="myblock" destination="page.wrapper" before="main" /> or
<move element="myblock" destination="page.wrapper" before="page.main" /> or
<move element="myblock" destination="page.wrapper" before="page-main" />
```

How can I put my block before that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with below code

```
<referenceContainer name="someuniquename" before="main.content">
```

Use some unique name.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="someuniquename" before="main.content">
            <block name="myblock"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Make sure, you have proper [block and template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113969/creating-custom-header-extending-magento-blank-in-magento-2) insted of `<block name="myblock"/>`. Then only you can identify wheter your block and template is at the right place.

Comment: I've found other container's name but still not work :(

Comment: I finally find out what's the problem with this. It's all about the name which may just like you said.