# Move search box in magento 2 to right side of menubar and add a div tag immediate next line of menu without any space or padding between

Tags: magento2

I wanted to add the search box to right of the menu bar. I also wanted to add division tag immediate below of the menu bar without any white space or padding.! How can I do this.? Thank you in advance.

**Update:** default.xml

```
 <!--  Moving block elements and rearranging to have in order of logo,toplinks , minicart , top navigation menu and search bar  -->
   <move element="header.panel" destination="header.panel.wrapper"/>
   <move element="logo" destination="header.panel"/>
   <move element="top.links" destination="header.panel" after="logo" before="minicart"/>
   <move element="minicart" destination="header.panel" before="-"/>
   <move element="top.search" destination="page.top" after="catalog.topnav" before="-"/>
    <move element="top.search" destination="catalog.topnav" after="-"/>
 <!-- Remove default elements -->
   <referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true"/>

 <!-- Adding logo -->
     <referenceBlock name="logo">
             <arguments>
                 <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo.png</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">400</argument>
                 <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
             </arguments>
         </referenceBlock>
 <!--adding blocks below main nav -->


 <referenceContainer name="page.top">
         <container name="belowNav" as="belowNav" label="Below Nav" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="belowNav">  
             <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="div-below1.nav"  template="Magento_Theme::testtry.phtml"></block>

         </container>
          </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To your extended question " add div tag immediately below the menu "

1 ) Create a block , where you can place your DIV or any content inside that like some offer are placed below menu . I have displayed the block on home page only , selected display on specified page, you can do for all page

[image]

2) Now create a widget , select the block you created first and then do below layout settings to display the block just below navigation bar

[image]

**option 2 adding via template**

add below code to your extended default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <container name="belowNav" as="belowNav" label="Below Nav" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="belowNav">  
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="div-below1.nav"  template="Magento_Theme::html/container1.phtml"></block>

        </container>
         </referenceContainer>
```

and place container1.phtml file inside

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/container1.phtml
```

Run deploy and cache commands. You also need to do some css settings to style the text and container . I typed hello in my container1.phtml

[image]

if any issue then let me know

Thanks

Comment: Thanks but..I wanted to make it in code by adding templates.

Comment: please check my updated answer , try option 2, if any problem then let me know thanks

Comment: I m not getting it right ..  I have added my default.xml to the  edited  question pls check if anything is wrong

Comment: did you placed the given code in default.xml file and created container1.phtml under given path ??

Comment: sorry.. check now..!!

Comment: yes ofcourse I can see the div.. but there occurs a white space between nav and div

Comment: i have dited my question with the picture of my output..

Comment: that is because of this class .nav-sections  which has margin from bottom so you need to remove that margin via css

Comment: remove margin and check all, I hope you got the right output which you were looking for . Thanks

Comment: made margins of menu 0px but still not getting it right! could anyone support

Comment: nav.navigation {
  display:inline;
  margin:0px;
}

Comment: This is culprit class .nav-sections and do not inline any css , use  _extend.less under this path app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less  you can write all your CSS or less here . run upgrade and deploy commands for compiling less

Comment: yes I a using _extend.less inside Magento_theme... .. I wrote this piece of code inside _extend.less ?? what should I write instead

Comment: .nav-sections{margin-bottom:0px;} and run commands to compile less

Comment: how do you find which class name to use ??

Comment: I inspect through browser, right click inspect element

Answer (score 1):

If you want move search bar to header(top.links),

create custom theme, then create this file

```
<magento-root>/app/design/frontend/<vendor-name>/<theme-name>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

Add below content:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout  /etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <move element="top.search" destination="catalog.topnav" after="-"/>
</body>
```

After, clear cache, then check it.

Reference: http://gworks.mobi/blog/2016/06/07/magento2-move-elements-block/

Comment: I wanted to add it in right float to navigation bar. yes I am doing this using my custom theme

Comment: @Priya I update my answer

Comment: Got the search box right .Thank you .. My extended question to add div tag immedietly below the menu without white space?? !! can you help it out I am trying hardly for about a day!

Comment: follow this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113969/creating-custom-header-extending-magento-blank-in-magento-2 to add custom div